# Is there any function to add Vertical Shaded Regions to Line Chart in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, line-plot

I want to create a line chart in Python that features vertical shaded regions like that pictured below:
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szCsp.jpg)

These shaded region data are there in form of a categorical variable in my dataset.

I would like to add vertical shaded regions in this chart to illustrate whats is level of respiratory rates while performing different phases of exercise activities. I have a dataset that has timestamps, respiratory rates, and phase of exercise activity in form of a categorical variable (WARMUP, EXERCISE, REST) Is it possible to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in matplotlib. You can use `axvspan` method of axes.For reference please go through this following link. You have to define the lower and upper limit of x axis based on your categorical values and also the color for that range and then feed those limits and color to `axvspan` method.

```
axvspan(1.25, 1.55, facecolor='g', alpha=0.5)
```

The above line will draw a vertical, green, translucent rectangle from x = 1.25 to x = 1.55 that spans the yrange of the axes.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of this method. But in my case, I want to color the region based on the categorical variable. In the above scenario, I have to give a range of x-axis. Instead, I want to be based on the categorical column of my dataset. My dataset has three columns Timestamp, respiratory rates, Phase of exercise. I want to color the region based on phase variable

Comment: @Kapil You can define a range based on your categorical column, like a dict whose key are the categorical values and the value for each key is the range in the form of a list. So based on the categorical value, you will get the range and then you can use `axvspan`.